# How to setup autowiring for classes from external non-spring project

Tags: spring

I have a requirement wherein I define a contract in Spring project and want to autowire an external JAR during deploy that implements the contract (set of interfaces). I do not want to enforce the external JAR to be Spring-dependent so that it is as flexible as possible. Is it not possible in my Spring project to use the classes from external JAR as autowire substitutions wherever I am using my contract interfaces? Let me explain with an example:

```
Spring project:
@Controller
public class MyController {
     @Autowired
     private MyInterface interface;
}
```

Now the JAR implementing the contract interfaces may be provided by client and I may not know the package names before hand and it could even be a non-Spring project, so it may not be declared with @Component annotation.

e.g.

```
public class CustomerClass implements MyInterface {
}
```

Now in my spring project, is there a way to inject CustomerClass in place of MyInterface? I hope my question is clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Paddy,
Regarding to your concern about whether you can traditional XML way to achieve the same goal. The following is a sample code showing how to achieve it. Note: the interface **MyInterface** cannot be dynamic in this way, because the controller is holding a refernece to **MyInterface** .

Spring application context config :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations" value="classpath:test.properties" />
</bean>
<bean id="myInterface" class="${myinterface.impl}"></bean>
```

MyInterface and two different implementation class

```
package au.net.test;

public interface MyInterface {

    public String getMessage();
}

public class MyClass1 implements MyInterface{

    public String getMessage(){
        return "message from class 1";
    }
}

public class MyClass2 implements MyInterface{

    public String getMessage() {
        return "message from class 2";
    }   
}
```

test.properties file under classpath(you can use ant script and maven profile to change property value)

```
myinterface.impl=au.net.test.MyClass2
```

web layer Controller (you can inject the implementation class based on dynamic bean candidate)

```
@Autowired
private MyInterface myInterface;
```

Comment: This properties approach looks good for my case and I am planning to use it. Thanks once again @spiritwalker

Comment: @Paddy Please be kind enough to acknowledge and accept the post as the answer , that the least you can do for the poster who took time to answer your query

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got you point. If that is the case, your question title should be **How to inject dynamic type of class by Spring Container** Now let's talk about the solution. First, you need to have some kind of properties to hold fully qualified class name. And then you can register you custom bean at runtime into spring container.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/applicationContext*");
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) applicationContext.getBeanFactory();
            //register your bean at runtime 
        beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("myClass", BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition("au.net.test.DynamicClass").getBeanDefinition());
            //retrieve you bean from spring container
        Object myBean = applicationContext.getBean("myClass");
            //cast to the type of your bean class or interface (be really careful)
        System.out.println(((DynamicClass)myBean).getMessage());


package au.net.test;
//this is the bean gets looked up and injected at runtime
public class DynamicClass {
    //simple method to verify it is working
    public String getMessage(){
        return "this is testing message";
    }
}
```

In the code above, you just need make "au.net.test" property value driven rather than hard coding.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Honestly a better title did not strike me then. Is there a context xml way of doing the first code snippet above instead of Java code? If Java code is the only way, where (meaning which class) exactly do I place this snippet? To have this code in every controller class that needs a specific contract interface, may not be a neater way, I guess.

Comment: you don't have to duplicate the code everywhwere. You can centralized the code to a separate class and provide a public method for your controllers to get bean. By the way, is the **MyInterface** gonna be dynamic as well or static?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Of course MyInterface is static :)

Comment: If the interface is static, the the third answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use factory-bean along with factory-method

```
<bean id="serviceProvider" class="package.ServiceProvider">

<bean id="myInterface"
      factory-bean="serviceProvider"
      factory-method="createMyInterfaceInstance"/>
//it might or might not to be a singleton factory, depending on your requirement.
public class ServiceProvider{
  private static MyInterface myInterface= new CustomerClass();

  private ServiceProvider() {}

  public MyInterface createMyInterfaceInstance() {
    return myInterface;
  }
}
```

So basically the idea here is that you have to create your own factory class and factory method for creating instance, depending on your factory, it might create singleton or prototype istance. And then just leave the rest of jobs to spring container.

Comment: Hi, <br/> Correct me if I my understanding is wrong, but in the example you have shown, the class attribute indicates the package, which in my case may not be known at compile-time. The JAR file path may be provided as a property during 'ant package' or 'maven install/deploy'. So I may not be able to declare this way, isn't it? <br/> Thanks, Paddy

Comment: "package.ServiceProvider" has nothing to do with JAR file path, it is just **fully qualified class name**. I'm not sure how come a **fully qualified class name** is determined at runtime in your case. If the class name cannot be resolved, how can you reference it in your client code?

Comment: May not be a valid use case, but I am just trying to see if the client JAR can be just integrated with my project by giving the path to the JAR. In other words, I wish to have a project to which you can attach a client JAR that implements a contract I know and start using it without knowing the client JAR package structure. My project will then  be a template project (or call it a template product) that can be integrated with any client implementation without knowing anything about the specifics of client JAR (including package name). Don't know if this is valid/possible?